# Why does mypy does not work with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mypy

I have the following code (snippet):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

with pip I installed

```
$ pip install -U sqlalchemy[mypy] sqlalchemy-stubs mypy
$ pip list | egrep -i '(sqlal|mypy)'
mypy                          0.982
mypy-extensions               0.4.3
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.42
sqlalchemy-stubs              0.4
SQLAlchemy-Utils              0.38.3
sqlalchemy2-stubs             0.0.2a29
```

Still, when running `mypy file.py`, I'm getting:

```
$ python3 -mmypy test.py 
test.py:1: error: Module "sqlalchemy.orm" has no attribute "declarative_base"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm using Python 3.10.5 from within a virtualenv.

What can I do to debug more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a problem of sqlalchemy.

> sqlalchemy.ext.declarative package is now integrated into the
> sqlalchemy.orm namespace

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#change-5508

Seems like its not working correctly with mypy, but I didnt dig deeper.

It is working fine, when I import declarative_base "the old way" like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

Answer (score 4):

Install sqlalchemy with `sqlalchemy2-stubs`

> poetry add "sqlalchemy[mypy]"

And then update `mypy.ini` with

> plugins = sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy 2.0 was completely overhauled for native compatibility with static type checking. You will have to refactor existing code following the [migration guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html). There is a [deprecated Mypy plugin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/mypy.html) that can be used in the interim, but I found it unstable (several months ago) so I gave up on it and refactored my code.